# How can I make a turn stay in my tic-tac-toe game?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a tic-tac-toe program. This program is hot seat type game (user v user). I wrote the part of the program which prints an x anywhere on the board, but i need help on making the move stay. Right now it puts an x where you want it on the board, but it doesn't save for the next move.

Here is the code (I'm not done with the rest of the program):

```
class Game

  def initialize
    @board=Array.new
    @board[1]="__|"
    @board[2]="__"
    @board[3]="|__"
    @board[4]="\n__|"
    @board[5]="__"
    @board[6]="|__"
    @board[7]="\n  |"
    @board[8]="  "
    @board[9]="|  "

    @turn = "x"
  end

  def show_board
    @board.each do |i|
      print i
    end
  end

  def set_turn #switches turns
    if @turn == "x"
      @turn == "o"
    else @turn == "o"
      @turn == "x"
    end
  end

  def make_move
    puts "Enter x coordinate"
    x=gets.to_i
    puts "Enter y coordinate"
    y=gets.to_i
    if y==1

      if y==1
        if x==1
          @board[1]="_x|"
        end
      end

      if y==2
        if x==1
          @board[2]="_x"
        end
      end

      if y==3
        if x==1
          @board[3]="|x_"
        end
      end

      if y==1
        if x==2
          @board[4]="\n_x|"
        end
      end

      if y==2
        if x==2
          @board[5]="_x"
        end
      end

      if y==3
        if x==2
          @board[6]="|x_"
        end
      end

      if y==1
        if x==3
          @board[7]="\nx |"
        end
      end



      if y==2
        if x==3
          @board[8]="x "
        end
      end
    end

    if y==3
      if x==3
        @board[9]="|x"
      end
    end


  end

  def check_win

  end
end


class Square
  def set_value

  end

  def value

  end

  def initialize
    @value
  end
end

g=Game.new
g.show_board
g.make_move
g.show_board
```

Comment: You might wish to make `Board` an object in it's own right instead of just an Array and then have it keep track of state internally while presenting modifier actions as public methods.

Comment: another tip would be having the board be an array of arrays so you can check it like this board[x][y] and take out a million if statements

Comment: also if you're just making a game (without the webapp side) i'd recommend using hosu (which is build off of gosu).  find an example here: https://github.com/tomprats/blast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An aside: So this would probably be a good exercise to start yourself tdd-ing your work.  Write the test for the behavior you want to see, watch it fail then make it pass.  That will help you drive out a solution.

Anyway, you have mismatched if/end opening and closing in there right now. That is probably causing you the problems. In make move you have if y==1 twice.

```
class Game
  def initialize
    @board=Array.new
    @board[1]="__|"
    @board[2]="__"
    @board[3]="|__"
    @board[4]="\n__|"
    @board[5]="__"
    @board[6]="|__"
    @board[7]="\n  |"
    @board[8]="  "
    @board[9]="|  "

    @turn = "x"
  end

  def show_board
    @board.each do |i|
      print i
    end
  end

  def set_turn #switches turns
    if @turn == "x"
      @turn == "o"
    else @turn == "o"
      @turn == "x"
    end
  end

  def make_move
    puts "Enter x coordinate"
    x=gets.to_i

    puts "Enter y coordinate"
    y=gets.to_i

    # if y==1
    if y==1
      if x==1
        @board[1]="_x|"
      end
    end

    if y==2
      if x==1
        @board[2]="_x"
      end
    end

    if y==3
      if x==1
        @board[3]="|x_"
      end
    end

    if y==1
      if x==2
        @board[4]="\n_x|"
      end
    end

    if y==2
      if x==2
        @board[5]="_x"
      end
    end

    if y==3
      if x==2
        @board[6]="|x_"
      end
    end

    if y==1
      if x==3
        @board[7]="\nx |"
      end
    end

    if y==2
      if x==3
        @board[8]="x "
      end
    end

    if y==3
      if x==3
        @board[9]="|x"
      end
    end
  end

  def check_win
  end
end

class Square
  def set_value
  end

  def value
  end

  def initialize
    @value
  end
end
```

Fixed and working :-)

Also - this construction would make it easier to see those if/end mismatches:

```
def make_move
  puts "Enter x coordinate"
  x=gets.to_i

  puts "Enter y coordinate"
  y=gets.to_i

  @board[1]="_x|"   if y==1 && x==1
  @board[2]="_x"    if y==2 && x==1
  @board[3]="|x_"   if y==3 && x==1
  @board[4]="\n_x|" if y==1 && x==2
  @board[5]="_x"    if y==2 && x==2
  @board[6]="|x_"   if y==3 && x==2
  @board[7]="\nx |" if y==1 && x==3
  @board[8]="x "    if y==2 && x==3
  @board[9]="|x"    if y==3 && x==3
end
```